# How to evaluate expression runtime in angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

i am new in angular and trying to evaluate expression at runtime in angular but failed.this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Operant1: <input ng-model="Operant1">
Operantion: <input ng-model="Operantion">
Operant2: <input ng-model="Operant2">
<h1>You entered: {{parseInt(Operant1) parseInt(Operantion)  parseInt(Operant2)}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Operant1 = 2;
    $scope.Operantion = +;
    $scope.Operant2= 3;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this area is not evaluate dynamically. is there any way to do it without using any custom function defined in scope and calling it from expression?

### EDIT

i tried this way too but fail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Operant1: <input ng-model="Operant1">
Operantion: <input ng-model="Operantion">
Operant2: <input ng-model="Operant2">
<h1>You entered: {{Calculate(parseInt(Operant1), Operantion,  parseInt(Operant2))}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Operant1 = 2;
    $scope.Operantion = +;
    $scope.Operant2= 3;

$scope.Calculate= function(op1,opt,op2) {
    if(opt==="+")
    {
        return op1+op2;
    }
    else if(opt==="-")
    {
        return op1-op2;
    }
    else if(opt==="*")
    {
        return op1*op2;
    }
    else if(opt==="/")
    {
        return op1/op2;
    }
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### i rectified my mine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Operant1: <input ng-model="Operant1">
Operantion: <input ng-model="Operantion">
Operant2: <input ng-model="Operant2">
<h1>You entered: {{ Cal(Operant1, Operantion,  Operant2) }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Operant1 = 2;
    $scope.Operantion = "+";
    $scope.Operant2= 5;

$scope.Cal= function(op1,opt,op2) {
    if(opt==="+")
    {
        return parseInt(op1)+parseInt(op2);
    }
    else if(opt==="-")
    {
        return parseInt(op1)-parseInt(op2);
    }
    else if(opt==="*")
    {
        return parseInt(op1)*parseInt(op2);
    }
    else if(opt==="/")
    {
        return parseInt(op1)/parseInt(op2);
    }
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you can't interpolate an operator.

Comment: I think I see what you're asking now, the answer is no you can't do that see the other comment with the link about how expressions are parsed or read up on the $parse and/or $interpolate source to see what it's doing under the hood

Comment: @shaunhusain does mine updated answer looks good? or seems like an hack.. your thoughts would appreciated.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use javascript `native` methods directly over the HTML inside angular binding. Basically whatever you wrote is indirectly evaluated by `$parse` API with scope values. So `parseInt` method isn't there inside controller scope, then it wouldn't evaluated there.

I'd say that create an method that will do whatever required calculation.

**Markup**

```
<h1>You entered: {{cal(Operant1, Operantion, Operant2)}}</h1>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.cal = function(op1, op, op2) {
   var op1Parsed = Number(op1), //converting to number
       op2Parsed = Number(op2), //converting to number
       //creating string to be parsed.
       customExpression = op1Parsed + (op || "+") +op2Parsed; 
   //parsing a html manually to make calculation working
   return eval(customExpression);
};
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/W59b4Uk0zwIZsX6tV2pp?p=preview)

Comment: i want to supply +,-,* etc by textbox. i do not want to hard code + or - etc

Comment: @Mou I got the question by reading it 4th time.. let me update my answer in a few minute..

Comment: Just wanted to add the link to the docs that explain this as well https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression  Anywhere in the angular API/reference where it says something about an "angular expression" these rules for parsing apply.

Comment: @PankajParkar give me full working code if possible. thanks

Comment: @Mou look at the updated answer which has plukr attached with demo

Comment: @PankajParkar do not understand this area `      $scope.cal = function(op1, op, op2) {
        debugger
        var op1Parsed = Number(op1),
          op2Parsed = Number(op2),
          customExpression = op1Parsed + (op || "+") +op2Parsed;
        return $parse(customExpression)($scope);
      };`

Comment: mm interesting... I was thinking something like this but maybe just with plain JS eval() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval using the $parse inside of the interpolation might be a little heavy given this thing is going to run on every digest since it's in an interpolation without the one time data binding... interesting nonetheless :)

Comment: what is Number function ? what is customExpression ? are u using any other js lib or function defined in some where?

Comment: @shaunhusain first thing I don't thing so evaluating some simple `calculation` expression, on each digest cycle wouldn't be heavy process. You are correct we could also use `$scope.$eval` instead of `$parse`, but if you look at `$eval` API, it uses `$parse` service, so I'd say using `$parse` service would be great(by having one indirect call to $parse). now remaining point is about one time binding, I don't thing its need here as value of calculation is gonna be changing on change of input..

Comment: @PankajParkar I actually mean the regular eval for just executing some string as though it's JS so you could skip out on any of the angular layers in that case.  Anyhow like you said since it's just doing some JS it's not going through a set or anything it shouldn't be more than a small blip in the timeline or profiling (have just been focused on optimizations lately).

Comment: @shaunhusain I got your point now.. `eval` would best for this case.. sorry for my mis-interption..Thanks for your valueable comment.. I was thinking in too much in angular way :-D

Comment: @PankajParkar apparently it happens to the best of us... thought you might get a kick out of this http://plnkr.co/edit/cN4byiptqyLAC7kbrDb1?p=preview seeing that makes me think this could be dangerous but I'm not quite sure how yet.

Comment: @shaunhusain may I known, how it would be dangerous?

Comment: @PankajParkar was mostly thinking if someone used this in a page where it wasn't necessary to expose that kind of functionality then a malicious hacker type might use it to get some other script running on the page and if the stars aligned they might be able to get keystrokes or the like from a user.  It's pretty far fetched but running any user input as code always starts to worry me.

Comment: what is $interpolate and $parse ? any built in directive....if yes then what they do?

Comment: They are services which used to evaluate data from scope..do use code mentioned in answer